# Call Method several times

Tags: ios, methods

I have an application that shows the user their current position. Yet, the first time I call the function it shows the wrong address, but after the second call it usually shows the correct one.

I want to call the function that gets the address 5 times before showing the results, and therefore increase accuracy for every call.

```
- (IBAction)getCurrentLocation:(id)sender {
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Is there any easy way to do this?

Thank you in advance, all the best

Comment: locationManager delegate calls back for you,

Comment: Could it be that the first time you get old location data. You should check the age of the location data in your delegate method and decide whether to show it.

Comment: I'm not sure you are familiar with the `CoreLocation.framework` and how it works at all: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/_index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling the reverse geocoding method multiple times with the same data will not improve the accuracy of the information - only receiving a more accurate positional fix will do that.

Core Location will call your `didUpdateLocations` delegate method when it has new location information.  You should get a call to this method as soon as you call `startUpdatingLocation`, but the location may not be very accurate if the GPS receiver is not already initialised.

The most recent location is the last object in the `locations` array sent to your delegate method.  You can examine the `[horizontalAccuracy][1]` property of the `CLLocation` to get the radius (in meters) of the circle of uncertainty for the location.  You can use this information to decide if you want to display the address to the user or continue to wait for a more accurate location.

Be aware though that you may never receive a more accurate location if the user is indoors or GPS reception is otherwise obstructed.

Answer (score -1):

Check the location manager delegate methods:

```
Responding to Location Events
– locationManager:didUpdateLocations:
– locationManager:didFailWithError:
– locationManager:didFinishDeferredUpdatesWithError:
– locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation: Deprecated in iOS 6.0
Pausing Location Updates
– locationManagerDidPauseLocationUpdates:
– locationManagerDidResumeLocationUpdates:
Responding to Heading Events
– locationManager:didUpdateHeading:
– locationManagerShouldDisplayHeadingCalibration:
Responding to Region Events
– locationManager:didEnterRegion:
– locationManager:didExitRegion:
– locationManager:didDetermineState:forRegion:
– locationManager:monitoringDidFailForRegion:withError:
– locationManager:didStartMonitoringForRegion:
Responding to Ranging Events
– locationManager:didRangeBeacons:inRegion:
– locationManager:rangingBeaconsDidFailForRegion:withError:
Responding to Authorization Changes
– locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:
```

Implement these and then you can update your UI once the location is what you expect ? Or just after a set number of times it's updated.